# Задание по react JS. Как сделать одновременное изменение состояния переключателя у всех пользователей?

Tags: reactjs

Есть переключатель, который при нажатии меняет фон на черный или белый. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на выключатель любым из пользователей фон менялся у всех пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о сайте, нужно написать бэкенд. Бэкенд будет хранить переменную в БД. Пользователь, нажимая переключатель, будет отправлять обновленную переменную в БД, а другие пользователи будут получать обновление этой переменной от бэкенда.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно в моем комментарии?

Comment: ты написал не комментарий... Ты сделал ответ. Но таким "ответом" ТС не воспользуется. Напиши это как комментарий к его вопросу.

Comment: @ksa Спасибо. Я только вошел. Еще не разобрался. :)